# Как подключить визуальный редактор CKeditor?

Tags: jquery, javascript, редактор

Из какого файла и как подключить [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) Basic? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

надо подключить файл ckeditor.js, который лежит в корневой папке скрипта. 
Далее(в простейшем случае) создать textarea с именем, айдишником(любыми) и классом ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR.replace(name,
{
    toolbar : 'Basic'
});
```

В конфиге или любом JSнике после подключенного CKeditorа

Comment: Ага...Только мне Basic нужен (Минимальный набор - там всего 6 кнопок ещё :) )

Comment: Поправить в конфиге. name - Имя(id) вашего редактора